# String int variable clarification

Tags: java, string, class, int, type-conversion

I have received the following error message

```
G:\CIS260\Assignments>javac PhoneNumber.java
PhoneNumber.java:45: error: incompatible types
        number = decode(c);
                       ^
  required: int
  found:    String
1 error
```

in the beginning of the class i have

```
char c;
private int number = 0
```

This makes it an int so i understand that in order for the next line to compile i have to have two of the same data types. My understanding is that

```
str[1].valueOf(number);

number = decode(c);
public static String decode(char c){

 switch (c) {
```

should make the variable NUMBER a string making decode and number equal data types because they are both strings.

I feel like i may be forgetting a step in order to make both strings data types. any thoughts?

Comment: what is c here. post declaration of c too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert string to int in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5585779/how-to-convert-string-to-int-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

char c = 0; //is not declared and initalized

number  = Integer.parseInt(decode(c));

Answer (score 1):

yes you are declaring number as Integer.

so you should cast it by using Integer.ParseInt.

Comment: Pedantic: You mean "convert", not "cast".

Answer (score 1):

You have the method `public static String decode(char c)` which returns a value of `String`, but the variable `number` accepts the value `String` which is declared as an `Integer`

Try having a return type of `Integer` like `public static int decode(char c)`

Answer (score 1):

Your method returns a `String`.

You are trying to store that returned string in an `int`.

Java does not convert strings to integers automatically like this. You will have to do the conversion explicitly. You can use [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) for this:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(decode(c));
```

Note that a `NumberFormatException` will be thrown if the returned string isn't actually a valid integer.